# Parse the datestring which contain 0000 through moment Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

If DateString value is "**19780000**".
Then display only year like **"1978"** in UI page through ***moment***.js

If DateString value is "**19781100**".
Then display month and year like "Nov 1978" in UI page through ***moment***.js

If it is not achieved by ***MOMENT***.js then how can it do by ***javascript***.

Kindly help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems too bespoke for a library to handle, especially the "0000" part - should only be a couple of lines to slice/substring, check if 0 then convert to the format you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple function to generate a string. It assumes the year portion of the string will be valid.

```
function dateStringToUI(ds) {
  const months = [null, "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
  let uiString = "";
  if (ds.length == 8) { 
    let yearPart = ds.substr(0, 4);
    let monthPart = months[parseInt(ds.substr(4, 2))];
    uiString = (monthPart !== null) ? `${monthPart} ${yearPart}` : yearPart; 
  }
  return uiString;
}
```